# Ember: Underscore model name in JSON while saving model

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have a problem with my Ember + Rails app.

I have a model called GuestGroup. I use ActiveModelAdapter to connect to my Rails back-end. When I save the model to my backend, Ember sends the following json:

```
{guestGroup: {title: "test", wedding: "1"}}
```

As you can see, the model name is in camelCase. But I expect it to be snake_case:

```
{guest_group: {title: "test", wedding: "1"}}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why ActiveModelAdapter doesn't convert model name to snake_case? It
   reads underscored JSON from server without problems.
2. How can I send my model name underscored?

Comment: The ActiveModelAdapter should definitely be doing this for you... can you provide some more code as to how you are sending this JSON?  And do you have any custom setup on your adapter or serializer?  Also what version of Ember? In the latest versions of Ember the ActiveModelAdapter is it's own addon and not included by default anymore.

Comment: @bmeyers you're right, the problem is that I have a custom Adapter for that model(I need to override the URL where Ember POSTs JSON to create new records). If I remove the adapter everything works fine.
Ember 2.0, Ember-Data 2.0. Now i try to use  format.

Answer (score 0):

I had a custom adapter for my model. And my custom Adapter was extending RESTAdapter - it was wrong. Now I extend the ActiveModelAdapter and it works fine:

```js
import UrlTemplates from "ember-data-url-templates";
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend(UrlTemplates, {
  urlTemplate: '{+host}/weddings/{weddingId}/guest_groups{/id}',
  findUrlTemplate: '{+host}/guest_groups/{id}',

  urlSegments: {
    weddingId(type, id, snapshot, query) {
      return snapshot.belongsTo('wedding', { id: true });
    }
  }
});
```